# Matlab using r divide twice in one expression

Tags: matlab

If I want to calculate:

```
var(B(k))=sigma^2(X'X+k*I_p)^-1*(X'X)*(X'X+k*I_p)^-1
```

where `sigma` and `k` are constants, `I_p` is an identity matrix of the correct dimension and `X` is an `n*p` matrix

in MATLAB is this the correct syntax?

```
var_alpha_Ridge=sigma2*(Gamma+lambda)\Gamma\(Gamma+lambda);
```

where `Gamma=(X'X)` and `lambda=k*eye(p)`.

Comment: To divide it `/` and to solve system it \. The \ is also call mldivide. What you want to do at the end ?

Comment: I am trying to replicate this R code: var.alpha.k<-sigma2[1]*solve(Gamma+lamda*diag(p))%*%Gamma%*%solve(Gamma+lamda*diag(p))

Comment: This suggests that mldivide is the correct answer?

Comment: try it. But I'm not sure you can so it in one expression. Maybe you need some middle step by storing result and after doing another mldivide after, I'm not sure.

Comment: That's the problem I'm not sure either and I have no result to benchmark it to!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to do it via the `/` and `\` operators, it would be

```
var_alpha_Ridge=sigma2*(Gamma+lambda)/Gamma\(Gamma+lambda);
```

However, I'd prefer to precompute the inverse

```
iGl = inv(Gamma+lambda);
var_alpha_Ridge=sigma2*iGl*Gamma*iGl;
```

If you are worried about numerical stability, use `pinv` instead:

```
iGl = pinv(Gamma+lambda);
var_alpha_Ridge=sigma2*iGl*Gamma*iGl;
```

Since the matrix you are inverting is probably well-conditioned because of the `lambda` part, I wouldn't expect large differences between the three ways to compute it.